# How can i use sum ? with more then 2 key

Tags: c#, sql

This is my table structure.

[image]

I want to use SUM for Ingredients.Recipe_Ingredient_Gr and Ingredients.Recipe_Ingredient_Piece for each Recipe in selected order.

My english is not enough to tell u exactly what i mean but i'll try to tell u with example.

in my program user will create stock data and after that they'll create recipes for food
and then they create Orders and add recipes in that orders so what i want to do is when they select order and press calculate they'll know how much total  gr Ingredient they need for that order.

i'm looking for sum command but i dont know how to use it with this table structure

Edit*

This is my table structure

```
> Stock(ID(PK),Ingredient_Gr,Ingredient_Piece,Ingredient_Name,Unit_Price,Total_Price)
> Ingredient(Stock_ID(FK),Recipe_ID(FK),Recipe_Ingredient_Gr,Recipe_Ingredient_Piece,Ingredient_ID(PK))
> Recipes(Recipe_Name,Recipe_Instructions,Recipe_ID(PK))
> Recipes_Orders(Recipes_ID(FK),Order_ID(FK),Recipes_Orders_ID(PK))
> Orders(Order_ID(PK),Date_Start,Date_End,Order_Piece,Date_Range,Range_Piece,Order_Name)
```

Desired result for example

Let's say for order_ID 1 (we have range_piece 200)

we have Recipe_ID 2 and 3

Recipe_ID 2 = Ingredient_ID  4 5gr and Ingredient_ID 6 7gr

Recipe_ID 3 = Ingredient_ID 4 10 gr

My result should look like this for order_ID 1

- -Ingredient_ID                     4            6
- -Ingredient_Name                   a            b
- -Recipe_Ingredient_Gr              15 gr        7 gr
- -Recipe_Ingredient_Piece           0            0
- -Unit_Price                        2            3
- -Range_piece                       200          200
- -Total Price                       2x200x15     200x3x7

  ```
   SELECT        Orders.Range_Piece, Orders.Order_ID, Stock.Ingredient_Name, Stock.ID, Ingredients.Recipe_Ingredient_Piece, Ingredients.Recipe_Ingredient_Gr, Recipes.Recipes_ID FROM            Ingredients INNER JOIN
                    Recipes ON Ingredients.Recipe_ID = Recipes.Recipes_ID INNER JOIN
                    Stock ON Ingredients.Stock_ID = Stock.ID CROSS JOIN
                    Orders
                    Where Order_ID=22
  ```

This query will give me this

[image]

i dont want to see malzeme 2 malzeme 2  i want to see there just 3 Malzeme like total malzeme 1 total malzeme 2 total malzeme 3

Comment: Tag your database and could you provide table structure and sample data with expected result all in text format?

Comment: i'll edit my question right now !

Comment: @KutayYorgun question is still unclear, you should provide some sample data. Also why would you want to add all gms for all ingredients for a recipe like for pasta, why would you want to add 500gm pasta and 200 gm sauce and report 700 gm of ingredients.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi no if 2 different recipes in same order has same ingredient like salt i just want that total salt number so i can xUnit_PricexOrder_piece for total price that order


edit* i want total for each unique ingredients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more columns you include in the SELECT statement, the more columns you need to add to the GROUP clause (and the groupings have to *make sense*). It's not clear how the price of the ingredients for an order are computed. You mentioned `Range_Piece 200 200` and on the next line show `Total Price 2x200x15 200x3x7` yet on your query results `Range_Piece` is 7500 for all rows and I have no idea how that column, whatever that is but is related to an order and not an ingredient, figures into a price calculation. So I am just guessing as far as the price calculation:

```
SELECT Orders.Order_ID,
       Stock.ID,
       Stock.Ingredient_Name,
       SUM(Ingredients.Recipe_Ingredient_Gr) AS Total_Grams,
       SUM(Orders.Range_Piece * Stock.Unit_Price * Ingredients.Recipe_Ingredient_Gr) AS Total_Price
FROM Orders INNER JOIN Recipes_Orders ON Orders.Order_ID = Recipes_Orders.Order_ID
INNER JOIN Recipes ON Recipes_Orders.Recipe_ID = Recipes.Recipes_ID
INNER JOIN Ingredients ON Recipes.Recipes_ID = Ingredients.Recipe_ID
INNER JOIN Stock ON Ingredients.Stock_ID = Stock.ID
Where Orders.Order_ID=22
GROUP BY Orders.Order_ID, Stock.ID, Stock.Ingredient_Name
```

Comment: these are two different examples actually range_piece is just day count * Piece and we have unit_price for each ingredients and gr or piece for each ingredient too so total price is

Range_Piece x Unit_Price x Ingredient_Gr/piece

i'm tried ur select query and it give me this error

"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '.'."

Comment: It's very difficult to generate correct SQL without actual tables. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), which means you should use a site such as db-fiddle.com to create tables with some sample data that can be tested against. In this case, I believe I was missing a comma at the end of the first line (I will update my answer).

Comment: i had no idea that kinda site is exist i'll add my db if i can figure out how for my next questions .Your query just work like i want (there was some name mistakes there but not major things) Thanks for ur help !

Comment: Let me know what the mistakes were and I will edit the answer. Also, if the answer is correct otherwise, please ACCEPT the answer.

Comment: ofc  "_Unit_Price" should be "Unit_Price" and  "Recipes.Recipe_ID" should be "Recipes.Recipes_ID" that's it and can u help me how can i put that data on DGV so everytime i double click my order it'll run for that order ID ? in another dgv

Comment: Thanks; I've updated the SQL. DGV is a Data Grid View (I had to Google this)? Seems like you need to post a whole new question.